# Support SAML Keyrock

Tags: saml, fiware, fiware-keyrock

I'm looking for some documentation or paper to help me to make an example with Keyrock and SAML authentication.

I have a SP SimpleSamlPHP, but I don't know how configure to make it works with Keyrock IdM.

Answer (score -1):

The SAML compatibility Keyrock currently offers is the one that Keystone offers by default. So please, refer to Keystone documentation to check that.